# Move one element to the end of a list with flexbox

Tags: html, list, css, flexbox

How can I move "3" to the end of the list using CSS?

See [`jsbin here`](https://jsbin.com/tudizeh/1/edit?html,css,output)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.end {
  align-self: flex-end; /* this doesn't work; how can I move 3 to the end? */
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li class="end">3</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `order` property. In this case, `order: 1` works because the other elements have their order set to `0` by default.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.end {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="end">3</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set [`order`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp) - add `order:1` on the `end` element to place it at the end of the list - as we don't specify it for the other *flex children* they will take the default value of zero.

See demo below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.end {
  align-self: flex-end;
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="end">3</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
```